# Multiplying a textbox by a decimal number

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a calculator to multiply a decimal in one textbox by a number in another textbox and have the result appear in a different textbox.  See below for what I have so far.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox3.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        float first;
        float second;
        float output;
        first = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        second = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        output = first * second;
        textBox3.Text = (output.ToString());
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: Why do you declare your numbers as `float`s and then put `int`s in them?

Comment: My apologies I forgot to mention I am new to c# so I am still learning. Thank you for the feedback, I am trying to calculate a total tip and have it come out in textBox3.  So my user would enter the amount of the check in textBox1, enter how much they would like to tip in textBox2 which would in turn multiply box1 by box 2 and the total will come out in box 3.

Comment: @user3291166: in that comment you still didn't state the **problem.**

Comment: Again, what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is I cannot get my box 1 to multiply by the decimal in box2 and output the result in box3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `decimal` instead.You are using `float` and converting values to `int`, Why ?

```
decimal first;
decimal second;
decimal output = 0.0m;
var b1 = decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out first);
var b2 = decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out second);
if(b1 && b2) output = first * second;
textBox3.Text = output.ToString();
```

And instead of Disabling your textbox, make it `ReadOnly`

Change this line:

```
textBox3.Enabled = false;
```

To:

```
textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: What's the difference? You've posted an answer while not knowing what the problem is.

Comment: don't you see the problem? he is trying to convert values to integer.by doing that he will never get the correct result.

Comment: @Selman22, he would get the correct result with whole numbers. While I don't disagree it's an issue; it may not be *the* issue.

Comment: He's also setting `textBox3.Enabled` to `false` in form constructor instead of setting `ReadOnly` property. But you don't know what he's up to.

Comment: okey, I'm making some assumptions.And that makes my answer wrong?

Comment: Thank you Selman22, I am new to c# so I am learning how to accomplish different tasks.  Thank you for your assistance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3291166 I didn't know that sorry.Anyway, does this answer solve your problem?

Comment: No worries, I thank you for your help.  Sort of but this is for a tip calculator and I need box3 to total the tip and the check amount.  Right now all it does it give me the tip amount, not the entire total.

Comment: In that case output = first + (first * second)

Comment: It Worked!!! thank you all very very much for your assistance.